# How to import a class in AngularJS 1.6 component controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

What syntax do I have to use if I want to import a class inside a AngularJS 1.6 [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03) controller?

For example, I have the following component.

**app/phone-list.component.js**

```
// Register `phoneList` component, along with its associated controller and template
angular.
  module('phonecatApp').
  component('phoneList', {
    template:
        '<ul>' +
          '<li ng-repeat="phone in $ctrl.phones">' +
            '<span>{{phone.name}}</span>' +
            '<p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>' +
          '</li>' +
        '</ul>',
    controller: function PhoneListController() {
      this.phones = [
        {
          name: 'Nexus S',
          snippet: 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'
        }, {
          name: 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
          snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
        }, {
          name: 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
          snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
        }
      ];
    }
  });
```

And I have a class defined in a separate file, `player.js`.

**player.js**

```
export default class Player {
  constructor () {
    // define properties
  }
  loadVideo () {
    // do stuff
  }
  playVideo () {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

I want to use this class inside `PhoneListController()` like this:

```
let player = new Player();
player.loadVideo();
player.playVideo();
...
```

The class works if I put it in the controller file.

- I use [babel-standalone](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone)

I receive `unexpected token import` if I try to import it in the following way:

```
import Player from './player.js';
```

Comment: Can you add that file to your question?

Comment: I don't see how the question is related to Angular or a controller. Do you have any particular problems with [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the error that you have. It means that you have problem in JavaScript Polyfill [Try this](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es-module-loader)